# If $a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$, Find minimum $P=\sqrt{\frac{2a+bc}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b+ca}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c+ab}{3}}-\frac{3(a+b+c+abc)}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0: a^2+b^2+c^2+abc=4$. Find minimum $$P=\sqrt{\frac{2a+bc}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b+ca}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c+ab}{3}}-\frac{3(a+b+c+abc)}{2}$$

When $a=b=c=1,$ we get that $P\ge -3$ So we need to prove $$\sqrt{\frac{2a+bc}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b+ca}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c+ab}{3}}\ge \frac{3(a+b+c+abc)}{2}$$
I tried to use substitution $a=\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}}$ but it is complicated
Also, by AM-GM $$\sqrt{\frac{2a+bc}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b+ca}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c+ab}{3}}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{\frac{2a+bc}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b+ca}{3}}\sqrt{\frac{2c+ab}{3}}}\ge\frac{3(a+b+c+abc-2)}{2}$$
But I don't know how to prove that last one.

Hope some user here can help. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proof.**

According to the given condition, we can demonstrate the identity$$\frac{a^3}{2a+bc}+\frac{b^3}{2b+ac}+\frac{c^3}{2c+ab}=2-abc.\tag{1}$$
(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747300/if-a-b-c-0-abbcca-3-find-maximal-value-sum-dfraca-sqrta22a23/4749069#4749069) for detail proving.)

Now, apply AM-GM as$$\frac{3a^3}{2a+bc}+2.\sqrt{\frac{2a+bc}{3}}\ge 3a,$$and take cyclic sum on it, we obtain $$\sqrt{\frac{2a+bc}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2b+ca}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{2c+ab}{3}}\ge \frac{3(a+b+c)}{2}-\frac{3}{2}.\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{2a+bc}.\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2),$ the desired result follows.

Comment: (1) is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum is $-3$ when $a = b = c = 1$.

**Sketch of a proof**.

We have, for all $x \ge 0$,
$$\sqrt x \ge -\frac12x^2 + \frac32 x. \tag{1}$$

Using (1), it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}
\left[-\frac12\left(\frac{2a+bc}{3}\right)^2+ \frac32 \left(\frac{2a+bc}{3}\right)\right]
- \frac{3(a + b + c + abc)}{2} \ge -3$$
or
\begin{align*}
&54 + 9(ab + bc + ca) - 4(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) - (a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2) \\
&\quad- 39abc - 9(a + b + c) \ge 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

We can prove (2) by the pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.

The condition $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + abc = 4$ is written as
$$p^2 - 2q + r = 4. \tag{3}$$

From (3), we have
$$2 \le p \le 3, \quad 0\le q \le 3p - \sqrt{3p(p + 1)(4 - p)}. \tag{4}$$

From (3), using $r = 4 + 2q - p^2$, (2) is written as
$$-(q + 61/2 - 2p)^2 - 2p^3 + 39p^2 - 123p + \frac{3313}{4} \ge 0. \tag{5}$$

From (4) and (5), it suffices to prove that, for all $2 \le p \le 3$,
$$-\left(3p - \sqrt{3p(p + 1)(4 - p)} + 61/2 - 2p\right)^2 - 2p^3 + 39p^2 - 123p + \frac{3313}{4} \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.